# How to extract stat_smooth curve maxima in gpplot panel (facet_grid)?

Tags: ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, curve-fitting, facet-grid

I have created this plot with 18 grids using `facet_grid` command and two different fitting equations (for Jan - Apr, and May - Jun). I have two things that I need help with:

1. (may sound obvious, but) I haven't been able to find on the internet working codes extract a curve maximum for a `stat_smooth` fit. I'd appreciate if someone could show and explain what the codes mean. This is the closest I could find, but I am not sure what it means:

> ```
> gb <- ggplot_build(p1)
>
> curve_max <- gb$data[[1]]$x[which(diff(sign(diff(gb$data[[1]]$y)))==-2)+1]
> ```

2. How to add a vertical line to indicate max value on each curve?

[Data file (rlc2 <- read_excel)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11lxB_2EpPE_sRyOXXMpMhCFxHMZq27jZ/view?usp=sharing)

Plot

```
plot <- ggplot(rlc2, aes(par, etr, color=month, group=site))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(data = subset(rlc2, rlc2$month!="May" & rlc2$month!="Jun"),
              method = "glm",
              formula = y ~ x + log(x),
              se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = "log"), start=c(a=0, b=0, c=0)))+
  stat_smooth(data = subset(rlc2, rlc2$month=="May" | rlc2$month=="Jun"),
              method = "nlsLM",
              formula = y ~ M*(1 - exp(-(a*x))),
              se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(start=c(M=0, a=10)))+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(month), cols = vars(site))
plot
```

[field_rlc_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz6Wi.jpg)

Any other advice are also welcome. I am educated as programmer so my codes are probably a bit messy. Thank you for helping.

Comment: I recommend you compute the models outside ggplot and then plot the paramters needed on top of the data.

Comment: In that case, can you still compute the maxima using R? Is so, how would you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

First, fit the data and extract the maximum of the fit.

```
my.fit <- function(month, site,  data) {
  fit <- glm(formula = etr ~ par + log(par),
      data = data,
      family=gaussian(link = "log")
      )
  #arrange  the dersired output in a tibble
  tibble(max  = max(fit$fitted.values),
         site = site,
         month = month)
}

#Apply a custom function `my.fit` on each subset of data
#according to month and site using the group_by/nest/map method
# the results are rowbinded and returned in a data.frame

my.max<-
  rlc2 %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(month, site) %>% 
  tidyr::nest() %>% 
  purrr::pmap_dfr(my.fit)
```

Next, join the results back on your data and plot a geom_line

```
rlc2  %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(my.max) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = par, y = etr))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(data = subset(rlc2, rlc2$month!="May" & rlc2$month!="Jun"),
              method = "glm",
              formula = y ~ x + log(x),
              se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(family = gaussian(link = "log"), start=c(a=0, b=0, c=0)))+
  stat_smooth(data = subset(rlc2, rlc2$month=="May" | rlc2$month=="Jun"),
              method = "nlsLM",
              formula = y ~ M*(1 - exp(-(a*x))),
              se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(start=c(M=0, a=10)))+
  geom_line(aes(y=max), col="red")+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(month), cols = vars(site))
```

[image]

Comment: I ran into a problem when trying your solution. What package do I have to install to use the `nest()` function? Thank you for the help! I tried the `dplyr` package, but it returned could not find function.

Comment: Also, I presume the first part the `data` data frame is the same as `rlc2` ?

Comment: `nest` is a `tidyr` function. The subsequent reference to `data`is correct and refers in this case to the subsetted `rlc2` data set

Comment: You are welcome. If you find the answer acceptable then consider to accept and/or upvote it.